# Linq to XML returns no items when there are items in the XML

Tags: c#-3.0, linq-to-xml

I am trying to query some XML data using Linq because it's easier than using XPath and as a good "proof of concept" for my co-workers as to how we can use Linq.  Here is my XML:

```
<Booking>
    <ServiceCollection>
        <Service>
            <BookingID>10508507</BookingID>
            <AdditionalChargeID>1</AdditionalChargeID>
            <ServiceName>Fuel Surcharge</ServiceName>
            <ServiceCost>56.87</ServiceCost>
            <ServiceCharge>103.41</ServiceCharge>
            <showInNotes>0</showInNotes>
            <showInHeader>0</showInHeader>
            <BOLHeaderText />
        </Service>
        <Service>
            <BookingID>10508507</BookingID>
            <AdditionalChargeID>2</AdditionalChargeID>
            <ServiceName>Lift Gate at Pickup Point</ServiceName>
            <ServiceCost>25.00</ServiceCost>
            <ServiceCharge>42.00</ServiceCharge>
            <showInNotes>1</showInNotes>
            <showInHeader>1</showInHeader>
            <BOLHeaderText>Lift Gate at Pickup Point</BOLHeaderText>
        </Service>
    </ServiceCollection>
</Booking>
```

Now, here is my C# code (ignore the Conversions class; they simply make sure a default value is returned if the item is null):

```
var accessorials = from accessorial in accessorialsXml.Elements("ServiceCollection").Elements("Service")
    select new Accessorial
        {
            BookingID = Conversions.GetInt(accessorial.Element("BookingID").Value),
            Name = accessorial.Element("ServiceName").Value,
            Cost = Conversions.GetDecimal(accessorial.Element("ServiceCost").Value),
            Charge = Conversions.GetDecimal(accessorial.Element("ServiceCharge").Value),
            ShowInNotes = Conversions.GetBool(accessorial.Element("showInNotes").Value),
            ShowInHeader = Conversions.GetBool(accessorial.Element("showInheader").Value),
            BillOfLadingText = accessorial.Element("BOLHeaderText").Value
        };
return accessorials.ToList();
```

I have a Unit test which is failing because the count of accessorials (the "Service" node in the XML) is 0 when it should be 2.  I tested out this same code in LinqPad (returning an anonymous class instead of an actual entity) and it is returning the proper number of values, yet the code here returns no objects.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried accessorialsXml.Element("Booking").Elements(...) ?

Comment: Yes; doing that throws a NullRef exception somewhere in the select new code.  Checking LinqPad, Element("Booking") returns null, so chaining the others triggers the NullReferenceException.

Comment: Also out of curiosity I tried Elements("Booking") (plural) which returns 0 so everything after it returns 0.  As I said in LinqPad just Elements("ServiceCollection").Elements("Service") *is* returning values, just the same code in Visual Studio is returning 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug may lie in how you're getting `accessorialsXml` in the first place. Try outputting the contents of this object before doing the query, to make sure it's exactly the same as the string you're using in LINQPad.

Comment: That could be it, it's an XDocument converted from an XmlDocument in VS but an XElement in LinqPad.  I'll check that and post another comment.  In the meantime upvoting for pointing me towards a possible bug.

Comment: Okay I think I'm just stupid and might have misspelled a value.  If I remove all but one value, it's returning properly.  So let me investigate that further.  But again thank you for pointing me towards a potential bug.